# Decrease volume below minimum in Windows 8.1

Tags: audio, windows-8, volume-control

Without buying speakers and hoping they can be quieter. I'm using earbuds anyway.

I'd like a program with a slider/volume control from 0 to 100 or even finer like 0 to 1000.

The quietest on my laptop is still too loud for what I want before falling asleep.

I'll mention something I've tried already before it is mentioned: lowest laptop volume/lowest YouTube volume/open YouTube vid then go lowest volume on VLC. This works well but is a bit cumbersome. Would be nicer just to have a fine tune slider that controls everything.

Comment: Simlar Question: http://superuser.com/questions/321508/lower-volume-level-below-1

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html).

It's designed to allow custom methods of controlling the volume (ie setting it to your mouse wheel), but it also gives you much finer-grained control. You can define a key to increase/decrease volume by 0.1%

Comment: Don't let the drop down menu in volumouse make you think that you're limited to the values in the list provided. The user can type in numbers lower than the minimum 500 steps indicated. The reverse-direction mouse wheel option is pretty convenient too. A negative value flips the mouse wheel although it's not my preference

Answer (score 0):

speaker icon bottom right corner near the (time) click on it. (if left does not work, try right clicking on it) a slider bar should show up.

you may also have some sort of "specific sound card app" that might be hiding in bottom right corner.  if you see some sort of > "arrow" or like click on it and you might see the icon.  you should be able to find this under "control panel" as well.

you mention VLC... vlc has it's own volume slider, but also adjusts the windows system sound slider as well.  **been there done that too many times**

and one other place before i forget... start -> all programs -> windows accessories or windows something -> mixer or sound (shows like a speaker icon) or little gray box with little sliders on it = mixer.

normally mixer will only show up, if you have sound currently playing make it youtube, vlc, mp3 player, etc....  the mixer will have a "master system volume" and then should have a separate slider for the other application/s currently playing sound.

Comment: I've set all those to minimum volume. If someone knows of a program that gives you a finer slider, please post.